# Why does URL Rewrite module makes CLR stop in IIS 8.5?

Tags: .net, iis, clr, pool, url-rewrite-module

- Windows server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5
- Simple one-file index.html website
- In the Application pool selected .NET CLR 4.0

In this step website works. Then I install the URL Rewrite module for IIS. Don't add any rules for URL Rewrite, but when I open web-site in browser, the application pool for this site stops.

The error message:

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

The log from

```
%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2019-04-29 13:34:12
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2019-04-29 13:34:12 127.0.0.1 49200 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 503 5 AppOffline test.com29 13:34:12 127.0.0.1 49200 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 503 5 AppOffline test.com
```

This catalog has no log files:

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
```

When one uninstall URL Rewrite module, the pool of website starts to work normally.

Why doest URL Rewrite module makes CLR stop?

> UPDATE

Event Log message:

```
The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.
```

Then I added to applicationHost config bitness32

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost

<add name="RewriteModule" image="%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />
```

With bitness32 it doesn't stop the pool but I get this error in the browser:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Module "RewriteModule" could not be found
```

Comment: Check for EventLog messages

Comment: @Rich-Lang added log messages to the question

Comment: AppOffline A service unavailable error occurred (an HTTP error 503). The service is not available because application errors caused the application to be taken offline.  

Are there any Event Log Messages?

Comment: @Rich-Lang added EventLog messages to the question

Comment: Why are you adding that configuration to your config files?  All of that should be handled automatically. Also, it clearly had some Rewrite config before as it knew about the DLL to give the error.  What is the "data" portion of the event log?   Also, how did you install URL Rewrite?

Comment: Like one of the answers below said, you need to check the version you use, as some version of URL Rewrite simply breaks everything and you cannot use it.

Answer (score 2):

In event log I found the same message. I.e. The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

For me the solution that worked was to replace the "rewrite.dll". In 2 of our other server it was working fine and they were installed in 2017. So I just copied the "rewrite.dll" from that server and replace it on my new server.

For me the older version(v7.1.1952.0) of the dll works, but new version ( v7.1.1993.2351), which comes with the latest setup, doesn't work.

BTW you need to stop the IIS before you replace the dll and start again.

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar issue. After installing visual c++ 2013 redistributable and visual c++ 2015 redistributable  URL rewrite 2.1 runs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any entry in the application event logs pointing you to the reason for the crash, You can set up a crash rule in debug diag as well to collect automated crash dump in debug diag and then analyze over there itself, it will give you more insight if the event log doesn't help you much. %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles will have no files and it is a expected as the site has already crashed and disabled and the request is not even reaching the site

Comment: Added EventLog messages to the question. If I understand this right, I don't have any entry point because it's only one static .html file without app.

Comment: Addidng a precondition would only make it load for 32 bit applications but it won't solve the problem. I think you added a pre condition but still had some rewrite rules either in web.config or applicationhost.config which resulted in the latter 500 error. What is the data number in the event log, that would give the actual error code for the operation that failed. Also how did you install url rewrite, through web platform installer in IIS or as a standlone executable from the downloads and was a proper msi installed?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the solution from Alexander Borisov and it worked for me after install Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. It can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31068417)